# Stylish custom stylesheets do not work with SVG nodes

Tags: css, svg, stylish

I found a strange issue and I'm not sure if it's a bug or normal behavior. Maybe I've got something wrong?

I am trying to make a custom Stylish stylesheet to style some SVG elements. The stylesheet:

```
svg circle {
  fill: #1E90FF;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: black;
}
```

It should look like this (without the frame):

[image: image description]

The stylesheet refused to work when placed in Stylish but works when in the document. So I tried this as a snippet:

```css
svg.A circle {
  fill: #1E90FF;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg style="width: 100px" class="A" viewbox="0 0 70 70">
 <circle class="circle" cx="35" cy="35" r="30" />
</svg>
<svg style="width: 100px" class="B" viewbox="0 0 70 70">
 <circle class="circle" cx="35" cy="35" r="30" />
</svg>

<div id="testdiv">
This is a reference test div to test that your stylesheet is working.
</div>
```

And used this custom stylesheet via Stylish:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stacksnippets.net") {
  #testdiv {
    color: green;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  svg.B circle {
    fill: #1E90FF;
    stroke-width: 5;
    stroke: black;
  }
}
```

And what I see is this:

[image: image description]

I can't imagine why stylish would filter out the styles for CSS, that sounds like nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
[Tomáš Zato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35218233/331508) is correct.
See [the @namespace reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@namespace).

You need to include the SVG namespace like so:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml); 
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);

@-moz-document domain("stacksnippets.net") {
    #testdiv {
        color: green;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    svg.B circle {
        fill: #1E90FF;
        stroke-width: 5;
        stroke: black;
    }
}
```

---

Stylish doesn't filter out styles (Inspect [the source code](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish)).
But it does inject them at the Chrome level above/outside/before the normal DOM. <sub>(That's the reason why Stylish can fix CSS without any of the annoying flicker that userscript-applied CSS sometimes has.)</sub>

<s>I'm just guessing, but *maybe* there's some kind of issue with Firefox about SVG and these kinds of "outside DOM" styles?</s>
Note that your style works perfectly fine in Chrome with the Chrome Stylish extension.

An alternate approach is to inject the CSS into the DOM, like so, using a userscript:
(Except in a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script, just use [GM_addStyle()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle).)

```js
function addStyle (cssStr) {
    var D               = document;
    var newNode         = D.createElement ('style');
    newNode.textContent = cssStr;
    var targ    = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (newNode);
}
addStyle ( `
    #testdiv {
        color: red;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    svg.B circle {
        fill: #1E90FF;
        stroke-width: 5;
        stroke: pink;
    }
` );
```

```css
svg.A circle {
    fill: #1E90FF;
    stroke-width: 5;
    stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg style="width: 100px" class="A" viewbox="0 0 70 70">
    <circle class="circle" cx="35" cy="35" r="30" />
</svg>
<svg style="width: 100px" class="B" viewbox="0 0 70 70">
    <circle class="circle" cx="35" cy="35" r="30" />
</svg>
<div id="testdiv">
    This is a reference div to test if your stylesheet is otherwise working.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it turned out it's probably correct behavior. When I removed the `@namespace` stuff from the stylesheet it was fixed. I think the XHTML namespace excludes the CSS or something... Still, this answer shows an useful way of adding stylesheet using userscript, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why, but this issue is resolved by removing the namespace part:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
```

This applies to both Firefox and Google Chrome. I'm not knowledgeable about the namespace stuff, but seems like the XHTML namespace probably restricts the CSS to HTML tags.

Comment: It looks like you would either use 2 namespaces: `@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@namespace svg url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);`  or omit it like you did.  Omitting the namespace carries a miniscule risk of styling things that you did not intend to.